# My Graphic card is dead or not?

Tags: windows, graphics-card

I have an Acer V5 and after I changed my HDD I reinstalled Windows 8 and when I install the nVidia driver or constructor driver my screen is scrambled and I cannot see anything!

When I uninstall driver everything looks fine...

How can I know if my graphic card is dead?

I have dual graphic card (nVidia & Intel)

Comment: What do you mean by "constructor driver"?

Comment: The driver proposed by Acer on Download page

Comment: Are these drivers are supported to Windows 8? and the recent ones?. Probably, it is an issue with the improper driver update and not an issue with your graphic cards. Also, check precedence of the graphic card in the bios, if any.

Comment: I think it's supported because before changing my HDD, I was on Windows 8 and everything was working fine... How can I check precedence of the grapgic card in the bios?

Comment: Exactly which model of Aspire "V5" do you have?

Comment: It is: Acer V5-571 PG

Comment: No one can help me?